# CTE Error (nvarchar to numeric)

Tags: sql-server, cte

I'm using a CTE to convert SSRS stored proc's into BO stored proc's, as apparently I can't use temp tables with Business Objects.

I'm having this query:

```
;WITH cte1
AS
( 
    SELECT  cv.issue  
          , cv.customfield  
          , CAST(STRINGVALUE AS NUMERIC) AS priority_num  
    --INTO    #temp_priority_val  
    FROM    proddb1.customfieldvalue cv WITH (NOLOCK)  
            INNER JOIN proddb1.customfield e WITH (NOLOCK)
                 ON  cv.CUSTOMFIELD = e.id 
                 AND e.cfname = 'Issue Priority')  

,cte2
AS
( 
    SELECT  a.ISSUE  
          , f.customvalue priority_num  
    --INTO    #temp_priority  
    FROM    cte1 a 
            INNER JOIN proddb1.customfieldoption f WITH (NOLOCK)
                 ON  a.CUSTOMFIELD = f.CUSTOMFIELD        
                 AND CAST(a.priority_num AS NUMERIC) = f.id) 

SELECT * FROM cte2
```

I keep getting an `Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric.` error on this execution.  The `priority_num` column is an nvarchar column that is CAST in the first CTE. When I execute this within the original statement that had the temp tables it works perfectly fine. It must be something with the CTE scope?

Answer (score 12):

You can't easily control the order in which SQL Server will evaluate the contents of a column that does not use the correct data type (or has mismatched precision). If you try to cast a column that is nvarchar to numeric, even if you have filters that should eliminate all non-numeric values from consideration, SQL Server can still try those first (see [Erland's complaint about this on UserVoice](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/d54d50d8-6f25-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0da0)). There are cases where you can nest CTEs until the cows come home, but SQL Server will still push or pull that evaluation to a place where you didn't expect it.

As long as aggregates and fulltext functions aren't involved (see [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/12945/1186) and [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20140329081147/http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/780132/)), you can force this evaluation before conversion by using a `CASE` expression. Here is a simplified version of your query with no CTEs:

```
SELECT cfv.issue,
  priority_num = CONVERT(NUMERIC(something, something), 
    CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(cfo.customvalue)=1 THEN cfo.customvalue END)
FROM
  proddb1.customfieldvalue AS cfv
  INNER JOIN proddb1.customfield AS cf
  ON cfv.CUSTOMFIELD = cf.id
  INNER JOIN proddb1.customfieldoption AS cfo
  ON cfv.CUSTOMFIELD = cfo.CUSTOMFIELD
  AND CONVERT(NUMERIC(something, something), 
    CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(cfo.customvalue)=1 THEN cfo.customvalue END) = cfo.id
  WHERE cf.cfname = 'Issue Priority';
```

You will need to change `something, something` to the proper precision/scale (or use one of the `int` types if you don't need decimal places). You should never declare varying types without specifying the length - [this blog post is about varchar, but it really applies to all of the types](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length).

If you are on SQL Server 2012 (it's always useful to include information like what version of SQL Server you're using), you can simplify this:

```
CONVERT(NUMERIC(something, something), 
    CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(cfo.customvalue)=1 THEN cfo.customvalue END)
```

to this:

```
TRY_CONVERT(NUMERIC(something, something), cfo.customvalue)
```

And it will actually be more reliable (since `ISNUMERIC` can return 1 and still fail at conversion time for specific types). [I blogged about this way back in 2002](http://web.archive.org/web/20150411061246/http://classicasp.aspfaq.com/general/what-is-wrong-with-isnumeric.html).