# The disappearing act of the "Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function" error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm running into the "Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function" error, but it goes away and the query works when I include the column I'm passing into those functions, any clue?

Doesn't work:

```
SELECT 
  SQT.QUOTATIONID, 
  UPPER(LEFT(Email.LOCATOR, CHARINDEX('@', Email.Locator) - 1)) AS Manager
  --, Email.LOCATOR
FROM SALESQUOTATIONTABLE AS SQT
INNER JOIN HCMWORKER AS H
    ON SQT.WORKERSALESRESPONSIBLE = H.RECID
INNER JOIN DIRPARTYTABLE AS D
    ON H.PERSON = D.RECID
INNER JOIN LOGISTICSELECTRONICADDRESS AS Email
    ON D.PRIMARYCONTACTEMAIL = Email.RECID
```

> Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function

Works:

```
SELECT 
  SQT.QUOTATIONID, 
  UPPER(LEFT(Email.LOCATOR, CHARINDEX('@', Email.Locator) - 1)) AS Manager 
  , Email.LOCATOR
FROM SALESQUOTATIONTABLE AS SQT
INNER JOIN HCMWORKER AS H
    ON SQT.WORKERSALESRESPONSIBLE = H.RECID
INNER JOIN DIRPARTYTABLE AS D
    ON H.PERSON = D.RECID
INNER JOIN LOGISTICSELECTRONICADDRESS AS Email
    ON D.PRIMARYCONTACTEMAIL = Email.RECID
```

This is continuously repeatable, and the only change I made to the query was included the "Email.LOCATOR" column.
This query was working for years and just randomly stopped working today. I'm pretty certain it's a data issue, but am still perplexed why selecting the Email.LOCATOR column fixes the issue.

Comment: Some of the values in that column do not have a `@`. The charindex is calculated as 0 and the LEFT() gets -1 as parameter.

Comment: Check your Messages tab on the "working" query. You're probably getting the same error. You just happen to be seeing results before you hit an error (as @ypercubeᵀᴹ) alluded to. When you add the extra column to the `SELECT` list, SQL Server retrieves the results in a different order, so you get some results to return first before hitting a failure.

Comment: No error in the messages tab.

Messages tab says the following:


(1750 rows affected)

(1 row affected)

Note, I verified that 1,750 results is the correct record count too. So I'm definitely getting every record back that I should be.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ I understand what the error message means, but it doesn't make sense to me that the error is fixed just because I'm selecting the Email.LOCATOR column. Also, when I get the distinct list of Email.LOCATORs from this query, all of them have an '@' symbol in them.

Comment: I would bet that if you remove the joins and you only select from `Email`, you'll hit the error, with or without selecting the column. The list of emails from this query may all have @ but other emails (which should not appear in the results of this query) have not.

Comment: Problem with similar cause (I think): https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/108131/strange-behaviour-in-tsql-function-parameter-with-int-variable-or-null-behaves/108142#108142 Specifically what Aaron mentions in his answer: **"... because you can't always rely on SQL Server filtering rows before attempting calculations."**

Comment: And it may make sense to use a constraint to prevent junk, non-email data from entering the column in the first place... or use a computed column... or [store the parts of the email address separately](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2657/storing-email-addresses-more-efficiently-in-sql-server/)...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the issue is similar to this one: [Strange behaviour in TSQL function (parameter with int variable or NULL behaves differently)?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/108131/strange-behaviour-in-tsql-function-parameter-with-int-variable-or-null-behaves/108142#108142)

Specifically what Aaron Bertrand mentions in his answer:

> **... because you can't always rely on SQL Server filtering rows before attempting calculations**

What I think happens is that `Email.Locator` has some values that do not contain a `@`. When these values are processed, the `CHARINDEX()` is 0 and the `LEFT()` is called with parameter `-1`, so the error is thrown.

Bu why the error is thrown in one query and not the other? It's likely because the two queries are executed with different plans. The optimizer chooses a different plan (due to the extra column or due different statistics than last month or for whatever reason) and all the values of the column are read (and the calculations are done) before the joins to the other tables.

---

To avoid the issue, I suggest you use `CASE`, replacing

```
LEFT(Email.Locator, CHARINDEX('@', Email.Locator) - 1)
```

with:

```
LEFT(Email.Locator, CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('@', Email.Locator) > 0 
                         THEN CHARINDEX('@', Email.Locator) - 1
                         ELSE 0
                    END)
```

Comment: Probably a lookup is required when the other column is included in the output, or there is a better covering index for that case...

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, this makes more sense. And I'm assuming something caused the query plan to be updated which is why this was working before today and then "randomly' broke. Also, thanks for the link to Aaron Bertrand's related answer. The last question I have is why don't order of clause operations apply here? I had a better source but couldn't find it, but essentially isn't this the order that clauses are processed? - https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-execution-order-of-SQL-queries And if so, why wouldn't the ON clause in the joins get hit first and filter out the problematic rows?

Comment: Yes, the logical order of execution is `FROM - WHERE - GROUP BY - HAVING - SELECT - ORDER BY`. But that's only the logical order of execution. Optimizers are free to choose different paths though as long as the result is the same as if the logical order was followed. If all values had a @, then there wouldn't be a problem. Some people see this behaviour as a bug and I think there was a Connect item about it.

Comment: I have to say, the more I learn about the optimizer, the more I realize it's a mysterious creature. Thanks again for the info!

Answer (score 3):

In all likelihood, the issue is indeed a data issue. A new row has been added to the `LOGISTICSELECTRONICADDRESS` table, with a `LOCATOR` that has no "@" in it.

Changing the query means that the full value of `LOCATOR` has to be carried through to the final results. In that case, there's no particular advantage to performing the calculation until the final result set has been determined, so SQL Server is waiting until the end of the selection process to calculate the value of `Manager`.

Based on the results you're getting, *without* `LOCATOR` in the `SELECT` list, SQL Server is choosing to compute the value of `Manager` *before* deciding what the final result rows are. It's possible that value of `Manager` will be much smaller than the full value of `LOCATOR`, so calculating instead of carrying the full `LOCATOR` value forward would save memory. If the data from `LOGISTICSELECTRONICADDRESS` is joined into the result set data before some of the other tables are joined in, then the calculation could be performed on rows that *won't* be returned in the final result set.

---

You didn't ask how to fix this, but (for the sake of completeness), you should check the value returned by `CHARINDEX`. If you want rows where `LOCATOR` has no "@", you can use a `CASE` statement:

```
SELECT SQT.QUOTATIONID,
       CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('@', Email.Locator) > 0
         THEN UPPER(LEFT(Email.LOCATOR, CHARINDEX('@', Email.Locator) - 1))
         ELSE ''
       END AS Manager
FROM SALESQUOTATIONTABLE AS SQT
INNER JOIN HCMWORKER AS H
    ON SQT.WORKERSALESRESPONSIBLE = H.RECID
INNER JOIN DIRPARTYTABLE AS D
    ON H.PERSON = D.RECID
INNER JOIN LOGISTICSELECTRONICADDRESS AS Email
    ON D.PRIMARYCONTACTEMAIL = Email.RECID
```

(Of course, you could return the full `LOCATOR` value instead of an empty string, that's your call)

If you *don't* want to see rows where the "@" is missing, you can just check in the WHERE clause:

```
SELECT SQT.QUOTATIONID,
       UPPER(LEFT(Email.LOCATOR, CHARINDEX('@', Email.Locator) - 1)) AS Manager
FROM SALESQUOTATIONTABLE AS SQT
INNER JOIN HCMWORKER AS H
    ON SQT.WORKERSALESRESPONSIBLE = H.RECID
INNER JOIN DIRPARTYTABLE AS D
    ON H.PERSON = D.RECID
INNER JOIN LOGISTICSELECTRONICADDRESS AS Email
    ON D.PRIMARYCONTACTEMAIL = Email.RECID
WHERE CHARINDEX('@', Email.Locator) > 1
```

Tested on one of my own tables; it worked fine there.