# What is the safest method for order by cast()

Tags: sql-server, order-by, cast

My query looks a bit like this:

```
Select top (@n) *
From MyTable
Where IsNumeric(MyColumn) = 1
Order By Cast(MyColumn as int) desc
```

Occasionally Sql will produce a query plan that places the Sort operator ahead of the filter operator. This is problematic since the table can contain values which are non-numeric.

Is there a query hint I can apply to force the filter to always come first?

Or would it be better to write my order-by clause to safely handle non-numeric values? I've found two options for this, but I'm not sure which one is better:

```
Order By Cast(Stuff(MyColumn, 1, Patindex('%[0-9]%', 1), '') as int) desc
```

Or

```
Order By Case IsNumeric(MyColumn) When 1 Then Cast(MyColumn as int) else 0 end desc
```

Comment: Related question and answer: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/64489/cte-error-nvarchar-to-numeric/64493#64493

Comment: Your last option `ORDER BY CASE` is better, but as Aaron Bertrand pointed out in his [answer](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/12945/57105), `CASE` does not always guarantee left-to-right evaluation. So, the safest method would be two queries. First insert result of `SELECT ... WHERE IsNumeric = 1` into a temp table, then select from this temp table your final result.