# SQL Server 2019 executes unreachable code

Tags: sql-server, functions, sql-server-2019

*[Update: This question describes a bug which has been fixed in [Cumulative Update 5 for SQL Server 2019](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4552255/cumulative-update-5-for-sql-server-2019).]*

---

Consider the following repro example ([fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a7d81b741dbe78aa6fb94b1edec1d78a)):

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Repro (@myYear int)
RETURNS datetime
AS
BEGIN
    IF @myYear <> 1990
    BEGIN
        RETURN NULL
    END

    DECLARE @firstOfYear datetime;
    SET @firstOfYear = DATEFROMPARTS(@myYear, 1, 1);
    
    IF DATEDIFF(day, @firstOfYear, @firstOfYear) <> 0
    BEGIN
        RETURN NULL
    END

    RETURN @firstOfYear
END
SELECT dbo.Repro(0);
```

Obviously, that function should return the first of January 1990 if the input is `1990`, and `NULL` otherwise. Yes, I know that `DATEDIFF(day, @firstOfYear, @firstOfYear) <> 0` is a nonsensical operation. This is a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to demonstrate a potential bug, not production code.

Now let's execute `SELECT dbo.Repro(0)` on SQL Server 2017 and SQL Server 2019.

**Expected result**: `NULL`.

**Actual result on SQL Server 2017**: `NULL`

**Actual result on SQL Server 2019**:

> Msg 289 Level 16 State 1 Line 1
> Cannot construct data type date, some of the arguments have values which are not valid.

Apparently, SQL Server 2019 executes some of the code below the initial guard clause (`IF @myYear <> 1990`) even if it shouldn't.

My questions:

- Is this expected behavior, or did I find a bug in SQL Server 2019?
- If this is expected behavior, how do I correctly write a guard clause validating input paramters?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

This is a bug with the inlining of Scalar UDFs (or perhaps a bug with the query optimiser that is being exposed more by scalar UDF inlining). You can use `WITH INLINE = OFF` to turn off inlining for that function.

Using a variable instead of a constant shows a bit more detail

```
declare @myYear int = 0

SELECT dbo.Repro(@myYear);
```

[image]

- Node 5 defines `Expr1000 = CASE WHEN [@myYear]<>(1990) THEN (1) ELSE (0) END`
- Node 2 defines `[Expr1003] = Scalar Operator(CONVERT_IMPLICIT(datetime,datefromparts([@myYear],(1),(1)),0))`

These expressions are simplified when using the literal `0` to `1` and `CONVERT_IMPLICIT(datetime,datefromparts((0),(1),(1)),0)` respectively.

The `datefromparts(0` will throw the error when evaluated.

- Node 6 defines `Expr1002 = CASE WHEN [Expr1000] = (1) THEN (1) ELSE (0) END`

And `Expr1002` is used as a [passthru predicate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/archive/blogs/craigfr/subqueries-in-case-expressions) on a nested loops join (node 3). On the inside of that nested loops the constant scan (node 7) returns no columns.

So this looks like the same basic issue as [the answer here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/239324/self-referencing-scalar-function-nesting-level-exceeded-when-adding-a-select/239432#239432) where an expression on the inside of a nested loops protected by a passthru predicate is moved out into an unprotected region.

Comment: FYI Microsoft is aware and a fix should be available in the next Cumulative Update.  Thanks for reporting it, and sorry you hit this issue.

Comment: @ConorCunninghamMSFT: That's great, thanks for the feedback!