# Why do I need to use a sub query to filter down a grouped select?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, subquery

If I do this --

```
SELECT dv.Name
      ,MAX(hb.[DateEntered]) as DE
FROM 
    [Devices] as dv
    INNER JOIN 
    [Heartbeats] as hb ON hb.DeviceID = dv.ID
WHERE DE < '2013-03-04'
GROUP BY dv.Name
```

I get this error --

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 17 Invalid column name 'DE'.

If I do this --

```
SELECT Name, DE FROM (
    SELECT dv.Name
          ,MAX(hb.[DateEntered]) as DE
    FROM 
        [Devices] as dv
        INNER JOIN 
        [Heartbeats] as hb ON hb.DeviceID = dv.ID
    GROUP BY dv.Name
) as tmp WHERE tmp.DE < '2013-03-04'
```

it works as expected.

Can someone explain **why** I need to nest my main query as a subquery to limit my data set?

Also, is there maybe a better way to achieve the goal here? Retrieve all records from one table, and the single "top" related record ordered by `[DateEntered]` descending?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't reference an alias in the `WHERE` clause - this is just because of the order in which SQL Server parses the statement.

There have been many discussions about this here and on StackOverflow. A couple of examples that give some background:

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/19762/why-is-the-select-clause-listed-first/

[Why are queries parsed in such a way that disallows the use of column aliases in most clauses?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/21965/why-are-queries-parsed-in-such-a-way-that-disallows-the-use-of-column-aliases-in/)

An alternative would be:

```
SELECT dv.Name
      ,MAX(hb.[DateEntered]) as DE
FROM 
    [Devices] as dv
    INNER JOIN 
    [Heartbeats] as hb ON hb.DeviceID = dv.ID
GROUP BY dv.Name
HAVING MAX(hb.[DateEntered]) < '20130304';
```

Answer (score 4):

There are a couple of things that are important here.  First, there is a logical order of processing that occurs.  And, the assignment of your `DE` column alias in the `SELECT` clause occurs after the `WHERE` clause is processed.  So, the `DE` alias is not valid in the `WHERE` clause.

Note that the sub-query solution is logically processed before the outer query, so the `DE` alias is assigned to the column before you reference it.

You can alter the original query to do what you want.  Here's one way.

```
SELECT dv.Name
      ,MAX(hb.[DateEntered]) as DE
FROM 
    [Devices] as dv
    INNER JOIN 
    [Heartbeats] as hb ON hb.DeviceID = dv.ID
GROUP BY dv.Name
HAVING MAX(hb.[DateEntered]) < '2013-03-04'
```

Move your date test to the `HAVING` clause, where you can test aggregates.  This will exclude data after it's been grouped.  Hopefully, that's what you're trying to do.