# Alias of COUNT is not being "recognized" by SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have restored the Northwind database(https://northwinddatabase.codeplex.com/) from a backup file using SQL Server.

Trying to execute the following query results in error "Invalid column name 'products'.", product is an alias.

```
SELECT OrderID, COUNT(ProductID) products
FROM [NORTHWND].[dbo].[OrderDetails]
GROUP BY OrderID
HAVING products > 5;
```

What is the problem?

Comment: MySQL does allow this and AFAIK it doesn't create any more ambiguity than does allowing it in the `ORDER BY`. However SQL Server supports window functions `SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SomeColumn) AS RN FROM SomeTable HAVING RN > 10` wouldn't make any sense at all as the `ROW_NUMBER` is calculated after the `HAVING`.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The `SELECT` clause is logically processed after the `HAVING` clause. Therefore the aliases used in `SELECT` don't exist (yet) when the `HAVING` clause is processed.

On MSDN you can look at [SELECT (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189499.aspx):

> **Logical Processing Order of the SELECT statement**
>
> The following steps show the logical processing order, or binding order, for a SELECT statement. This order determines when the objects defined in one step are made available to the clauses in subsequent steps. For example, if the query processor can bind to (access) the tables or views defined in the FROM clause, these objects and their columns are made available to all subsequent steps. Conversely, because the SELECT clause is step 8, any column aliases or derived columns defined in that clause cannot be referenced by preceding clauses. However, they can be referenced by subsequent clauses such as the ORDER BY clause. Note that the actual physical execution of the statement is determined by the query processor and the order may vary from this list.
>
> 1. FROM
> 2. ON
> 3. JOIN
> 4. WHERE
> 5. GROUP BY
> 6. WITH CUBE or WITH ROLLUP
> 7. HAVING
> 8. SELECT
> 9. DISTINCT
> 10. ORDER BY
> 11. TOP

This query works because it repeats what will later be defined (the `COUNT`) in the `SELECT` clause:

```
SELECT OrderID, COUNT(ProductID) products
FROM [NORTHWND].[dbo].[OrderDetails]
GROUP BY OrderID
HAVING COUNT(ProductID) > 5;
```

Comment: +1. It's amazing that even the official documentattion doesn't get it entirely right (well, not so amazing but rather common for MSDN. It's at parts clumsily written and omits details). The `JOIN` and `ON` are part of the `FROM` clause and not independent clauses as the article implies.

Answer (score 8):

Because the `HAVING` is parsed *before* the alias has been generated in the `SELECT` list. This is explained in much detail [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/21965/why-are-queries-parsed-in-such-a-way-that-disallows-the-use-of-column-aliases-in/).

The only place you could use an alias is in the `ORDER BY` clause. A workaround is to repeat the expression in the `HAVING`:

```
    SELECT OrderID, COUNT(ProductID) AS Products
      FROM Northwind.dbo.OrderDetails
      GROUP BY OrderID
      HAVING COUNT(ProductID) > 5;
```