# I report SQL sysntax error

Tags: postgresql

I'm  getting sql error for the below
select

```
(select ((Select count(student_hash)from ssa.survey_results where question_master_id in (22)and center_id=101100 and answer_master_id in (95,96))*100/
(select (select case when exists((Select * from ssa.survey_results where question_master_id in (22)))then(Select count(student_hash)
from ssa.survey_results where question_master_id in (22))else 1 end)))As QUESTION22PERCENTAGE  from ssa.survey_results cd group by QUESTION22PERCENTAGE)Q22Percentage,

(select ((Select count(student_hash)from ssa.survey_results where question_master_id in (22)and answer_master_id in (95,96))*100/
(select (select case when exists((Select * from ssa.survey_results where question_master_id in (22)))then(Select count(student_hash)
from ssa.survey_results where question_master_id in (22))else 1 end)))As QUESTION22PERCENTAGE  from ssa.survey_results cd group by QUESTION22PERCENTAGE)Q22oPercentage,
(SELECT CASE WHEN Q22Percentage = Q22oPercentage THEN 'SAME'
            WHEN  Q22Percentage  > Q22oPercentage THEN 'BETTER'
            WHEN  Q22Percentage  < Q22oPercentage THEN 'WORSE'
            ELSE 'No comparison' END AS comparison)
            from  ssa.survey_results 
            group by Q22Percentage,Q22oPercentage;
```

I appreciate your help

ERROR:  column "q22percentage" does not exist
LINE 10: (SELECT CASE WHEN Q22Percentage = Q22oPercentage THEN 'SAME'
                           ^

Comment: select
(select ((Select count(student_hash)from ssa.survey_results where question_master_id in (22)and center_id=101100 and answer_master_id in (95,96))*100/
(select (select case when exists((Select * from ssa.survey_results where question_master_id in (22)))then(Select count(student_hash)
from ssa.survey_results where question_master_id in (22))else 1 end)))As QUESTION22PERCENTAGE  from ssa.survey_results cd group by QUESTION22PERCENTAGE)Q22Percentage,

and

Comment: (select ((Select count(student_hash)from ssa.survey_results where question_master_id in (22)and answer_master_id in (95,96))*100/
(select (select case when exists((Select * from ssa.survey_results where question_master_id in (22)))then(Select count(student_hash)
from ssa.survey_results where question_master_id in (22))else 1 end)))As QUESTION22PERCENTAGE  from ssa.survey_results cd group by QUESTION22PERCENTAGE)Q22oPercentage
from ssa.survey_results 
 group by Q22Percentage,Q22oPercentage;

Comment: I get results -- but when I'm adding case statement I'm getting error

Comment: Basically when i run both select statements -- i get the results -- only in CASE statements those Q22 and Q22o which are derived values ( which are not physically present in the table ssa.survey_results giving issue -- having said how do we compare both derived values to assign some values ?   CASE WHEN Q22Percentage = Q22oPercentage THEN 'SAME'---- first we are getting sum of values and then comparison -- Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are queries parsed in such a way that disallows the use of column aliases in most clauses?](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/21965/why-are-queries-parsed-in-such-a-way-that-disallows-the-use-of-column-aliases-in)

Answer (score 1):

The table `ssa.survey_results` does not have a column `Q22Percentage`

How much clearer can that message get?

Comment: How about "ERROR 2001: HEY DANGO, YOUR TABLE ssa.survey_results IS MISSING THE COLUMN q22percentage."

Comment: So "missing" and not "does not exist"?

Comment: When i run this piece I get the results