# Using Alias in Calculations

Tags: alias

I know that this Problem was addressed before but my SQL knowledge is not that good to figure it out. Maybe you can help me.

```
select 
    ProductionLine,
    Product, 
    POId, 
    BatchNumber, 
    Sum(Prime) as Prime, 
    Sum(Offspec) as OffSpec, 
    Sum(InQ) as InQ, 
    Sum(Prime) + Sum(Offspec) + Sum(InQ) as Total


from @t2 

group by 
    ProductionLine, 
    BatchNumber, 
    POId, 
    Product;
```

I now need a Column PercentagePrime where the column Prime is defined by the alias Total

Comment: Specify DBMS, including its version.

Comment: You can include the calculation multiple times (as you have done for Total) and do the math that way... SUM(PRIME) / (SUM(Prime) + SUM(Offspec) + SUM(InQ)) and that will work and probably not cost that much more in cpu time.  Otherwise look into whatever engine you are using's version of sub-queries / CTE.

Comment: Duplicate of [Why are queries parsed in such a way that disallows the use of column aliases in most clauses?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/21965/why-are-queries-parsed-in-such-a-way-that-disallows-the-use-of-column-aliases-in)