# Invalid Column Name on CONCAT_WS

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, join, concat

Sorry if this seems like rambling I'm not typically a DB person just trying to work through an issue.

I have two tables `cases` and `legal_entity` the data on the two tables looks like this

`legal_entity`

| first_name | last_name | address_1_zip |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Maria | Munoz | 33122 |
| John | Glenn | 10003 |
| Melissa | Johnson | 90210 |

`cases`

| style | case_number | create_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Munoz, Maria | SL12345 | 2021-03-01 11:45:26.657 |
| Glenn, John | SL45678 | 2021-03-02 12:10:14.552 |
| Johnson, Melissa (DNY) | SG42561 | 2021-04-10 01:06:10.214 |

What I am trying to do is combine the `last_name` and `first_name` fields from the `legal_entity` table with a comma between them, and match (contains) it against the `style` field in the `cases` table. For everything in the last month basically. This is the query I'm using

```
SELECT
    first_name, last_name, address_1_zip,
    CONCAT_WS(',', last_name,first_name) AS CombinedName
FROM
    CPSQL.dbo.legal_entity AS LE
INNER JOIN CPSQL.dbo.cases as C ON LE.CombinedName=C.style
WHERE C.create_date >= Convert(datetime, '2021-03-01') AND C.create_date <= Convert(datetime, '2021-04-16')
ORDER BY C.create_date
```

The issue I run into is that it seems to not like the LE.CombinedName so I'm not sure how to reference the concatenated string against the style column in the cases table.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Related: [Why are queries parsed in such a way that disallows the use of column aliases in most clauses?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/21965/why-are-queries-parsed-in-such-a-way-that-disallows-the-use-of-column-aliases-in)

Comment: You are welcome to post an answer, but it should not be part of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use only columns from the joined tables or in your case concatenated  version of it

```
SELECT
    first_name, last_name, address_1_zip,
    CONCAT_WS(',', last_name,first_name) AS CombinedName
FROM
    CPSQL.dbo.legal_entity AS LE
INNER JOIN CPSQL.dbo.cases as C ON CONCAT_WS(', ', LE.last_name,LE.first_name)=C.style
WHERE C.create_date >= Convert(datetime, '2021-03-01') AND C.create_date <= Convert(datetime, '2021-04-16')
ORDER BY C.create_date
```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE legal_entity
>     ([first_name] varchar(7), [last_name] varchar(7), [address_1_zip] int)
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO legal_entity
>     ([first_name], [last_name], [address_1_zip])
> VALUES
>     ('Maria', 'Munoz', 33122),
>     ('John', 'Glenn', 10003),
>     ('Melissa', 'Johnson', 90210)
> ;
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE cases
>     ([style] varchar(22), [case_number] varchar(7), [create_date] varchar(23))
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO cases
>     ([style], [case_number], [create_date])
> VALUES
>     ('Munoz, Maria', 'SL12345', '2021-03-01 11:45:26.657'),
>     ('Glenn, John', 'SL45678', '2021-03-02 12:10:14.552'),
>     ('Johnson, Melissa (DNY)', 'SG42561', '2021-04-10 01:06:10.214')
> ;
> ```

> ```
> SELECT
>     first_name, last_name, address_1_zip,
>     CONCAT_WS(',', last_name,first_name) AS CombinedName
> FROM
>     legal_entity AS LE
> INNER JOIN cases as C ON CONCAT_WS(', ', LE.last_name,LE.first_name)=C.style
> WHERE C.create_date >= Convert(datetime, '2021-03-01') AND C.create_date <= Convert(datetime, '2021-04-16')
> ORDER BY C.create_date
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> first_name | last_name | address_1_zip | CombinedName
> :--------- | :-------- | ------------: | :-----------
> Maria      | Munoz     |         33122 | Munoz,Maria 
> John       | Glenn     |         10003 | Glenn,John
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=68e5fcfd2352a27b138f1c9b1731cc3c)*

> ```
> CREATE TABLE legal_entity
>     ([first_name] varchar(7), [last_name] varchar(7), [address_1_zip] int)
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO legal_entity
>     ([first_name], [last_name], [address_1_zip])
> VALUES
>     ('Maria', 'Munoz', 33122),
>     ('John', 'Glenn', 10003),
>     ('Melissa', 'Johnson', 90210)
> ;
> GO
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE cases
>     ([style] varchar(22), [case_number] varchar(7), [create_date] varchar(23))
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO cases
>     ([style], [case_number], [create_date])
> VALUES
>     ('Munoz, Maria', 'SL12345', '2021-03-01 11:45:26.657'),
>     ('Glenn, John', 'SL45678', '2021-03-02 12:10:14.552'),
>     ('Johnson, Melissa (DNY)', 'SG42561', '2021-04-10 01:06:10.214')
> ;
> GO
> ```

> ```
> SELECT
>     first_name, last_name, address_1_zip,
>     CONCAT_WS(',', last_name,first_name) AS CombinedName
> FROM
>     legal_entity AS LE
> INNER JOIN cases as C ON PATINDEX( CONCAT( LE.last_name,', ',LE.first_name,'%'),C.style) > 0
> WHERE C.create_date >= Convert(datetime, '2021-03-01') AND C.create_date <= Convert(datetime, '2021-04-16')
> ORDER BY C.create_date
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> first_name | last_name | address_1_zip | CombinedName   
> :--------- | :-------- | ------------: | :--------------
> Maria      | Munoz     |         33122 | Munoz,Maria    
> John       | Glenn     |         10003 | Glenn,John     
> Melissa    | Johnson   |         90210 | Johnson,Melissa
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b8f52c15ff398803a1007e6bd0debca6)*

Comment: This looks to be working except for cases where `C.style` contains more information than just LastName,FirstName (Ex. Johnson, Melissa (DNY)) it doesn't match even if you change the = to LIKE.

Comment: yes but your question was about why is that not working, as the pattern go colpexer you will need much more soffisticated search pattern, and of you want also to compansate for mispellings you will open the next can of worms.